# Moving files between S3 buckets in parallel

Tags: multithreading, scala, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I have two S3 buckets under different accounts. I want to move files from Bucket A to Bucket B, and I want to do this as fast as possible. To accomplish this, I thought I'd use Scala, Asynchronous requests, and parallel processing to move the files as fast as possible.

In order to do this I have to call a listObjects command (which returns its own future, and then for each object returned by that command, I have to run a getObject and then a putObject in sequence. Consequently, listObjects should then spawn several getObject futures, and when those futures resolve, they should be followed by putObject futures.

I've been trying to make this happen in roughly this manner:

```
def moveData(listObjects: Future[ListObjectV2Response]) = {
  listObjects.isCompleted {
    case Success(objListResp) =>
      val getAndPut = objListResp.objects()
                                 .map(obj => getObject(obj.key))
                                 .map(obj => putObject(obj.key))
      moveData(ListObjects(objlistResp.continuationToken())
    case Failure(error) => error.printStackTrace()
}
```

I've tried some approach in this flavor about 6 different ways. I am consistently flummoxed by the following phenomena:

1. `.isCompleted` has a Unit response type, and I cant have that with a recursive function.
2. I often need to pass various values from, e.g. listObjects responses to PutObject requests. This leads to passing 3+ static values down the `.map` chain as futures.
3. listObjects is a single future, but calling the `.contents` returns an iterable that has to be converted into many different futures. This, combined with (2) leads to some really tricky uses of `map` and `flatMap` where scala wants the map/flatmap to be something like `Iterator[S3Object] => Future[NotInferred]` when the actual response type is `Iterator[S3Object] => Iterator((Future[GetObject], Future[String]))`

How do I approach this problem? Is there a better way?

EDIT:

There are thousands of files, many of them in the several GB. In total, the data to be copied is in the tens of terabytes. I have extremely limited access on the source bucket and the account it is in. I won't ever have the ability to do anything other than Get and List operations.

Comment: Does your source bucket get updated continously when you are moving data? 
Have you considered using Lambda? What is the characteristic of your S3 data ( small/big ? Lots of file or average ? )

Comment: You can use parallel collections right?

Comment: You can have a look at [Benji DSL](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/s3/usage.html) (I'm contributor of), that provides S3 operations using Akka Streams (so with support for async/reactive/streaming)

Comment: I presume you mean "copy" rather than "move", since you do not have delete permissions on the source bucket.

Answer (score 2):

If the two buckets are in **different regions**, you can use [Amazon S3 Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html).

If they are in the **same region**, the "fastest" way to get the objects copied is:

- Create an **Amazon S3 Event** to trigger an AWS Lambda function
- The **Lambda function** will receive the Bucket and Key of the object that triggered the event
- The Lambda function should **copy the object to the other bucket** by using the `CopyObject()` command

The benefit of this method is that there is **no need to list objects in the bucket** because the Lambda function will be triggered for each new object.

Comment: I cant do that - the source bucket is under the account of a third party, and they aren't going to let me do things like create events, run copy commands etc. The only permissions I have are `Get` and `List`, and they aren't going to give me anything else.

Comment: Another option is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command, which will do it all for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work either. In order to sync buckets across accounts, I need the source bucket to have a specific bucket policy that allows it. I don't have permission to do that, and the bucket owners won't do it for me.

Comment: To use `aws sync`, the source bucket needs to provide you with `ListBucket` and `GetObject` permissions. These are the same permissions you would need to copy the files out using your own code. Can you be more specific about the permission/policy that you require but do not have?

Comment: The source bucket needs to have a bucket policy that allows a destination _account_ to Get and List. See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/) documentation. I have an IAM user with Get and List only. I cannot create or attach said bucket policy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to write an extremely gross function that technically runs, although I'm getting errors that result from concurrency problems. Posting here for posterity, but I don't like this answer.

```
  def streamData(response: Future[ListObjectsV2Response]): Future[ListObjectsV2Response] = {
    var continuationToken: String = ""
    val operationChain = response.map((res: ListObjectsV2Response) => {
      println("LISTED - " + res.maxKeys())
      continuationToken = res.nextContinuationToken()
      res.contents().asScala.toList
    }).map((objs: List[S3Object]) => {
        for {
          obj <- objs
          fileName = obj.key().split("/").last
          getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(BucketA).key(obj.key()).build()
          writeFilePath = Paths.get("./" + fileName)
          future = BucketAS3.getObject(getObjectRequest, writeFilePath).toScala
        } yield {
          (future, Future(obj.key()), Future(writeFilePath))
        }
    }).map((futureSeq: Seq[(Future[GetObjectResponse], Future[String], Future[Path])]) =>
      futureSeq.map((futureTuple: (Future[GetObjectResponse], Future[String], Future[Path])) => {
        for {
          getObjResp <- futureTuple._1
          key <- futureTuple._2
          writeFilePath <- futureTuple._3
        } yield {
          println("DOWNLOADED - " + key)
          val putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketB).key("ability_dump/" + key).build()
          (BucketBS3.putObject(putObjectRequest, writeFilePath).toScala, Future(key), Future(writeFilePath))
        }
      })
    ).map((futuresSeq: Seq[Future[(Future[PutObjectResponse], Future[String], Future[Path])]]) => {
      futuresSeq.map((futures: Future[(Future[PutObjectResponse], Future[String], Future[Path])]) => {
        for {
          f <- futures
          putObjResp <- f._1
          key <- f._2
          writeFilePath <- f._3
        } yield {
          println("UPLOADED - " + key)
          val writeFile = new File(writeFilePath.toString)
          if (writeFile.exists) {
            writeFile.delete()
          }
          println("DELETED  - " + writeFilePath.toString)
        }
      })
    })
    streamData(BucketAS3.listObjectsV2(abilityListRequestBuilder.continuationToken(continuationToken).build()).toScala)
  }
```